# Deprecated CCMenu Images

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

What can I use instead of `itemFromNormalImage:selectedImage:disabledImage:target:selector`  It is deprecated in iOS 7, and I am new to programming in Objective C, so I don't know another way.

Comment: Look into ccDeprecated.h/.m to find the replacements for deprecated methods/properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this method](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_menu_item_image.html#a9d1cd4590c29e6e43083da9c4257b7e2)

```
+ (id) itemWithNormalImage:(NSString *) value selectedImage:(NSString *) value2 disabledImage:(NSString *) value3 target:(id) r selector:(SEL) s
```

If your code was this:

```
CCMenuItemImage *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" selectedImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(displaySceneSelection)];
```

Now it should be like this:

```
CCMenuItemImage *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" selectedImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(displaySceneSelection)];
```

Comment: So, just to clarify, my old code was:CCMenuItemImage *playGameButton = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" selectedImage:@"UIButtonTemplate.png" disabledImage:nil target:self selector:@selector(displaySceneSelection)];  What would I change now?

Comment: Just change the method name

Comment: The example I gave is identical to what you wrote, so does that mean I leave what i had and just add the new method. The code I wrote is still deprecated.

Comment: The method name is different. itemFromNormalImage has changed to itemWithNormalImage

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    CCMenuItemSprite *Menu1=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> selectedSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#>];
    CCMenuItemSprite *Menu2=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> selectedSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> block:<#^(id sender)block#>];
    CCMenuItemSprite *Menu3=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> selectedSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> disabledSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> block:<#^(id sender)block#>];
    CCMenuItemSprite *Menu4=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> selectedSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> disabledSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#>];
    CCMenuItemSprite *Menu5=[CCMenuItemSprite itemWithNormalSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> selectedSprite:<#(CCNode<CCRGBAProtocol> *)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#>];
```